# How do I turn off wordpress comments ability to capture a users ip address?

Tags: comments, ip

Going through the comments table on my wordpress site, I noticed that wordpress is storing the ip address of everyone who makes a comment on my site. How do I remove this functionality?

I'm not just talking about the display of the ip in the template, I mean I don't want wordpress to capture it in the first place.

Comment: As a plugin: [T5 No Comment IP](https://gist.github.com/toscho/3276726).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this to your functions.php:

```
add_filter('pre_comment_user_ip', 'no_ips');
function no_ips($comment_author_ip){
  return '';
}
```

You'll still have the comment_author_IP field in the db, but it will be empty...

And to remove existing IP records from the db run this query:

```
UPDATE `wp_comments` SET `comment_author_IP` = ''
```

Comment: thank you very much! That was a very nice little hidden gem of a function.

Comment: You could just set `__return_zero()` as filter function. No need to create a new one. :)