# How can I hide the IP of registered commentators?

Tags: comments, ip

There is already a related question at
[How do I turn off wordpress comments ability to capture a users ip address?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/20679/how-do-i-turn-off-wordpress-comments-ability-to-capture-a-users-ip-address)

But is there a solution to do it for users/mods/admins only?

So that normal anonymous visitors will have their IPs stored but registered users not.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a [check for the log in status](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_user_logged_in):

```
add_filter( 'pre_comment_user_ip', 'wpse_53935_no_ip_for_logged_users');

function wpse_53935_no_ip_for_logged_users( $ip )
{
    return is_user_logged_in() ? 0 : $ip;
}
```